# Covid-19 Testing - Walking distance from Disney World

Tags: usa, covid-19, disney, florida

I'm planning a trip to Disney World in the coming months.

I will be travelling from Canada with my son who is between two and three years old. Currently he is unvaccinated for COVID-19 as there are no vaccines available for his age.

It looks like the CDC requirements would require him to get a COVID Viral Test within 3-5 days of arrival according to [CDC - ATTACHMENT A](https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/pdf/NCEZID_FRM_Pass_Attest_Eng-508.pdf).

Questions:

1. Would a Rapid Test that I bring from Canada and administer myself be sufficient to satisfy this requirement?
2. If not, what is my best option for a qualifying COVID test within walking distance from any portion of Disney World (i.e. that I can reach via Disney Transport)? I would prefer to avoid taking a vehicle to avoid bringing his car seat.

According to my research so far, Advent Health Centra Care Lake Buena Vista is about a twenty-minute walk from Disney Springs and appears to be a walkable route. Is this my best option for a sufficient COVID test? Bonus if you can tell me what I might expect to pay for the testing as I couldn't find it on their site.

Thanks!

Comment: Orlando resident here.  There's not much within what I'd call reasonable walking distance of Disney World - especially in summer.  August in central Florida is pretty darn miserable for being outside.  If you come in the winter months it's quite nice though.  FYI, I believe they've just approved (or are about to?) vaccines for as young as 6 months in the US (no idea about Canada), so if you can manage to get that taken care of first you won't have to worry about it so much.  (Might need to get it from another state though, as Florida is being stupid about this currently.)

Comment: I assume you are flying to Disney World Florida, in the US and not to Paris, France, right? Your mention of "CDC" suggests that but you might want to clarify in your question.

Comment: Correct, Disney World Florida.

Comment: @reirab oh, OK. But it would still help to mention a country since that won't be obvious to all as I just demonstrated :)

Comment: @terdon Fair enough. I edited to add usa and florida tags.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll be fine with a rapid test.

https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/international-travel-during-covid19.html

> Get tested for current infection with a COVID-19 viral test 3-5 days after arrival.

This paragraph links to https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/testing/diagnostic-testing.html, which includes rapid self-tests as one of the listed test types.

If a PCR test were required, they would specifically say so.

Answer (score 7):

A few options:

- As ceejayoz says, a home test is acceptable.
- If you prefer a test given by a medical professional, the [Walgreens on South Apopka Vineland Road](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Walgreens/@28.3894325,-81.5091938,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88dd80199127156f:0x188846fb1838d027!8m2!3d28.3894325!4d-81.5070051) offers [PCR or NAAT testing by appointment](https://www.walgreens.com/findcare/covid19/testing?ban=covidtesting_LP_hero_schedule).
- The Advent Health location in your question also appears to be an option.
- You could also ask in your hotel for further options, this is a common question among travelers nowadays and they may have some additional insight.
- Depending on the timing of your trip, [Canada may approve vaccines for young children](https://www.ctvnews.ca/health/canada-could-approve-first-covid-shot-for-youngest-kids-this-month-feds-1.5975426) before you travel, making the whole question moot.

Answer (score 4):

I was there at Christmas when testing was more strict. We brought with us a pack of seven NHS tests.

On day 3 we tested both kids and took a photo of the result. There was no mechanism to log this result and no one asked us for proof at any point that we'd even tested them.

The negative pre flight and return tests (which at the time were required) were checked by the airline. The answers we got online from people who'd come back,  ranged from, "we didn't test them at all" to "we spent $300 on a test" via "we did our own in the room".

However, no one said they'd been asked for a proof of test. I have searched and I haven't found anyone reporting being caught out by this requirement, but would be fascinated if anyone else has.

Comment: Yeah, the US testing enforcement [looked about like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2uhWTFvug8) even at the best of times.

Comment: It is of course hilarious that American kids don’t have to get tested when coming from outside the US but foreign kids still do…

Comment: I would be interested how they could prosecute anyway, given how poorly explained the requirement is and how many questions like this I've read since I returned.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Nothing in my answer is about Disney as such. I stayed in a hotel walking distance from Disney. No one from Disney/state/border security/FBI checked that we'd tested our children. Nor was there any consistent advice at that time on where you needed to test or how you logged the result in Florida.

I didn't mention Disney once in my answer either.