# Do I have to test my two-year-old on COVID on arrival in the USA?

Tags: usa, covid-19, children, quarantine

My wife and I are fully vaccinated against COVID. Our two-year-old isn't. There is this obligatory [US_Passenger Disclosure and Attestation Form](https://infohub-resources-production.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2022_06_21_c2912d20-a0c5-4cb5-bfd2-8c6e0d5466cc.pdf) to be filled out by travellers who are not US citizens nor permanent residents.

For our two-year-old we must select

> B. NOT FULLY VACCINATED OR UNWILLING TO PROVIDE PROOF OF VACCINATION
>
> (**X**) I attest that I am (or the person I am attesting on behalf of is)
> excepted from the requirement to present Proof of Being Fully
> Vaccinated Against COVID-19 based on one of the following (make one
> choice, as applicable):
>
> (**X**) Child ages 2 through 17 years (complete D only, then sign the form to complete Attestation).

So the interesting part is section **D**:

> I attest that I am (or the person I am attesting on behalf of is) excepted from the requirement to present Proof of Being Fully Vaccinated Against COVID-19 and made the following arrangements (must check all boxes in D and then sign Attestation).
>
> [ ] **To be tested with a COVID-19 viral test 3-5 days after arriving in the United States**, unless I have (or the person has) documentation of having recovered from COVID-19 in the past 90 days;
>
> [ ] **To self-isolate for a full 5 calendar days** and properly wear a well-fitting mask any time I am (or this person is) around others during my (or this person’s) isolation period and for an additional 5 days after ending isolation,
>
> • if the result of the post-arrival viral test is positive, or
>
> • if I develop (or this person develops) COVID-19 symptoms.

Does this mean we **must** test our-two-year old for COVID on arrival and wait for the results in isolation? This would be horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All unvaccinated international travelers to the United States must take a COVID test; it doesn't matter *why* they are unvaccinated. If the test comes back positive (or if the traveler develops COVID symptoms after arrival), then they must must self-isolate for 5 days. Self-isolation is done in response to a positive COVID test or COVID symptoms, not speculatively.

*Some* unvaccinated international travelers additionally need to quarantine on arrival (which basically means they need to self-isolate *just in case* they have COVID, rather in response to *knowing* they have COVID). This does not apply to your child.

Also note that, contrary to what you said in your question, the COVID test must be administered 3-5 days after arrival, not "on arrival".

Comment: Do you have a source for that? I've been looking around for confirmation but could not find it.

Comment: @Hilmar Well, the attestation is linked in the original question. More details in the order: https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/pdf/CDC-Vaccine-Order-04-04-2022-p.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Now where to test? Does it have to be at official side, which will give you an test certificate (and who will ask for that certificate, do I have to show it to somebody). Or can we do a self-test after 3-5 days and store it?

Comment: @arminb I would say "you should ask that as a new question" but luckily [somebody already did](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174862/covid-19-testing-walking-distance-from-disney-world).

Comment: (tl;dr pick up a home test from a pharmacy. No need for certificates.)

Comment: @Hilmar: The CDC [page on the vaccination requirement](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html#noncitizen), also says it.

Comment: @user102008: As far as i can tell this page confirms indeed that children are exempted from vaccine requirements but I didn't see anything that said they are exempted from the 5-day self isolation requirements that comes with the vaccine exemption.

Comment: @Hilmar: Sorry, I missed that part of your question. Your child is required to take a COVID test 3-5 days after entry, and if the test is positive or they develop symptoms, they are required to "self-isolate" for 5 days. Your child is not required to "self-quarantine" for 5 days after entry, as answered by one of the answers [here](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html#faq). In the form you quoted, it does not say that the child needs to quarantine while awaiting results.